# Java test file works when I run as Junit Test, not working as Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

I have one java class file where I wrote my codes and one test file where I test my code.

I have generated my test cases via the Eclipse test generator and wrote my codes with @Test. When I run these codes with JUnit Test everything working, but I want to export as a jar and execute it. So, I need a main inside the test class. I searched google and StackOverflow

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore jCore = new JUnitCore();
        jCore.run(StackTest.class);
        System.out.println("In main method");
    }
```

Another approach;

```
public class testRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(AllTests.class);
        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
            System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

 TestRunner.runAndWait(new TestSuite(StackTest.class));

JUnitCore runner = new JUnitCore();
TextListener tl = new TextListener(new RealSystem());
runner.addListener(tl);
runner.run(StackTest.class);
// If above doesn't work, comment everything including imports and uncomment the following
org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main("StackTest");
   }
```

Like these solutions, but nothing worked for me. How can I make executable tests for Java Application not run as JUnit? Because I want to export test in a jar and execute it outside.

My Errors usually like below:

> JUnit version 4.12 .E Time: 0.005 There was 1 failure: 1)
>   initializationError(StackTest) java.lang.Exception: No runnable
>   methods   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateInstanceMethods(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:128)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:84)   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(JUnit4Builder.java:10)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:40)    at
>   org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:31)  at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:101)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:87)
>     at org.junit.runners.Suite.(Suite.java:81)    at
>   org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)  at
>   org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)     at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.createRequest(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:118)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:77)    at
>   org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)    at
>   StackTest.main(StackTest.java:144)
>
> FAILURES!!! Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re missing the fact that you need a test launcher to execute the tests, just like you need a `main` method to execute production code. Just packaging them in a JAR does precisely nothing.
JUnit 5 has the concept of a `Launcher`, see the docs.
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api

Comment: I fixed it writing "JUnitCore.main("com.ex.StackTest");" in the main of the not test file. It worked without Launcher. I was missing the fact of Launcher, I will check that out. Thanks.